# SSRS 2005: Get default menu selection from a query or other parameter

Tags: parameters, reportingservices-2005, default-value

I built a report with one parameter being a menu of names, and the default value being `<ALL>`

Clients wanted the default to be the person logged in.

I can easily get User!UserID the default for a text box, but if I change the menu from names to IDs, it will not pre-select it on the menu.  Instead, it adds the "" thing to the top of the menu.

Same thing if I make the defalut value the output of a query for which the input is the user ID.

Summary: If non-queried default is a literal, it works for menu or for text box.

If it is Non-queried `=User!UserID` it only works for text box.

If it is From query, it only works for text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh!

The menu has **values** and **labels**.

The section for the default clearly says **value**, not **label** !

Color me silly.